# windbg "Unable to read memory at ~~" error

Tags: windbg

When analyze minidump file on windbg, I want to extract file for memory arange.
So I try

> .writemem C:\f.dll 76dd0000 76ec0000
> ( 76dd0000 ~ 76ec0000 is kernel32.dll's start address and end address )

and I get result from windbg
"Writing f0001 bytes..
Unable to read memory at 76dd1000, file is incomplete"

How can solve this problem?
Enyone help please

Comment: There isn't much solution to this problem w/ the current dump: you're trying to read memory from the dump file and that memory isn't there. If possible, try to redo the dump with complete memory information, see the [.dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-dump--create-dump-file-) command (you're missing the mini option `c` to have image code sections included).

Comment: @Neitsa: will `.dump /mac` page in the code sections of DLLs when parts of them were swapped to disk?

Comment: @ThomasWeller good question :) I assume it does. I did a test w/ a program that I hadn't used for multiple hours, attached to it, `.dump /mac`, then extracted successfully `kernel32` and `kernelbase`. This proves nothing, but I'm pretty sure `MiniDumpWriteDump` touches the needed memory pages to get them back.

Comment: @Neitsa: thanks. I think `.dump /mac` will be my new default. /mac is so un-Windowsish :-D I think you should give that as an answer. I don't know anything better.